# C++ 11 - Is moving non local variable safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move

Say I have a function which goes like:

```
void a_fct( std::vector<double> &some_vector )
{
  std::vector<double> a_temporary_vector = some_vector;

  ... some stuff involving only a_temporary_vector ...

  some_vector = a_temporary_vector;
}
```

which is of course a bit silly, but it is just intended as bringing the following general questions:

- It seems to me that one should rather move `a_temporary_vector` into `some_vector` here, as it then goes out of scope. But is it safe to move `some_vector` into `a_temporary_vector` rather than copying ?
- Imagine now that somewhere else in the code, I have a pointer to the vector given as argument here. Is this pointer still pointing to it if I move `some_vector` into `a_temporary_vector` ?

In both cases, can I expect it to be true for any STL implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard (in 17.6.5.15) says:

> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (12.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

Thus, `some_vector` is required to have an (unspecified but) valid state after being moved from. You're allowed to move from it into you temporary and then move again from the temporary into `some_vector`.

```
std::vector<double> a_temporary_vector = std::move(some_vector);
// do stuff only on a_temporary_vector but not some_vector
some_vector = std::move(a_temporary_vector);
```

Pointers and references to `some_vector` itself are still valid but pointers or references to content of `some_vector` are not (as you would normally expect when passing an object to a function taking a non-constant reference).

*Note: You could use `swap` in this case instead if you're not sure about whether to move from it or not.*

```
void foo( std::vector<double> &some_vector )
{
  // swap contents of some_vector into temporary
  std::vector<double> a_temporary_vector;
  a_temporary_vector.swap(some_vector);

  // operate on temporary

  // swap content back into some_vector
  a_temporary_vector.swap(some_vector);
  some_vector = a_temporary_vector;
}
```

Comment: Why would swapping be any better than moving?

Comment: @juanchopanza It wouldn't and I didn't say so. It's just another way of avoiding to copy the content of the vector.

Comment: OK, so it doesn't answer the question(s).

Comment: @juanchopanza: My included side-note doesn't answer the question - true but not very striking I think.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all of the above is perfectly safe.

Moving into or from the argument vector does change it, but this is kind of what a non-const reference argument is meant to do anyway. The result of moving the temporary vector into to output parameter is equivalent to the copy method.

The pointer to the argument vector is no problem either. `some_vector` will still be the same object as before, you will just have changed its content.

Pointers, iterators and references to the original data of `some_vector` get invalidated of course, regardless of copy or move.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! I thought that somehow doing `... = std::move(some_vector);` was destroying `some_vector` and potentially used memory that was previously allocated to it.